# how in explorer 11 can i use FrameSet?

Tags: html, url, internet-explorer-11

### `index.html`:

[image: code]

The code can use chrome, Microsoft edge, but can't' use explorer 11 ..

explorer 11 show error message can't be used.

so i can't use JavaScript.

if you know how to apply fixing URL, please know me that.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Best practice is to include code in your question, not an image to the code.

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: You can use JavaScript,  what you shouldn't use is `frameset` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset . Can you be more specific, what is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript - jQuery at that - to set up a frameset in the first place? Why is the frameset only shown on automatic submission of a fake form?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well on my side (using IE 11.116.18362.0 version), please check your IE browser setting, and make sure you have enabled the JavaScript.

Detail steps as below:

1. Select the **Gear** in the upper-right corner of the screen or the “**Tools**” menu if you have the menu bar enabled, then select “**Internet Options**“.
2. Select the “**Security**” tab.
3. Select the zone you wish to modify. In most cases, it will be “**Internet**“.
4. Select the “**Custom level…**” button.
5. Scroll down to the “**Scripting**” area and select the radio button to “**Enable**” or “**Disable**” it “**Active scripting**“. You may also opt for IE11 to “**Prompt**” you to allow scripts to run.
6. Select "**OK**" to enable the setting.

The screenshot as below:

[image]

If still not working, please explain more detail error message.